# Stuck at 640x480 resolution on AMD 6800 series

Tags: resolution, gpu

Okay. Here's my problem. I am currently running an AMD 6860 GPU with two display outputs. One of them is a projector which connects through HDMI; the other is a monitor which connects through DVI. When I run the computer, the projector displays at the correct resolution of 1920x1080, while the monitor will not go above 640x480.

The monitor's native resolution is 1600x900, but any option to increase (or decrease!) the resolution is greyed out. I have tried using the AMD Catalyst Control Center to increase the resolution, but if I do, the monitor gives me an error message which pretty much says that the input is not valid. And then it goes black for 15 seconds before it reverts to the old graphics settings. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work without that projector plugged in? It could be an issue related to driving multiple displays.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't. When I boot the computer up, the boot sequence comes out of the HDMI and without the projector, I can't see anything at all.

Comment: most probably it's the driver. http://support.amd.com/de-de/download

Comment: It's not the driver--I reinstalled it and nothing happened. This problem didn't occur with my old GPU or with integrated graphics.

Comment: Okay, somehow I managed to increase the resolution to 1280 x 720, but I can't get it up to 1600 x 900. If I try to use the Show All Modes option or the AMD Catalyst Control Center, I get an **Input Signal Out Of Range -- Change Settings to 1600x900-60hz** error message. I'm on a HP 2009m if that helps.